# Rerun of Neural Network does not converge

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, convergence

I have a Convolutional Neural Network for semantic segmentation, implemented in Keras with Tensorflow backend. The architecture is of type encoder-decoder, using convolutional layers and max-pooling in the encoding part and deconvolutional layers and upsampling in the decoding part. Two classes to separate: objects of interest and background. Last layer has a sigmoid activation, the rest have Relu. There is one batch normalization layer in the "middle" of the model. Loss function is an Intersection over Union score. Learning algorithm : stochastic gradient descent, with learning rate 0.001 and momentum 0.9 .

I have trained the model and it achieved convergence with a quite good performance on the segmentation task. The trouble here, being a newbie in Neural Networks, I did not save any data regarding the learning progress : graphs with loss values, accuracy, etc. which I need to include in my report. Therefore, I tried to retrain the same network (nothing changed), but it does not converge (at all).

What to do in this case ? I did not choose any specific initializations for the weights ( as I understood and later checked, the default in Keras is glorot_uniform ), so naturally each time I run it, they will be different. Is there something I can do ? Or am I at the mercy of chance to reproduce the initial results ?

Any thoughts/suggestions/advices are most appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: I think there is nothing you can do right now to reproduce exactly the same results as it was. So I think the only thing you can do is not making this error again. To do this I recommend setting ALL random seeds to fixed values. I am not sure how to do this in Keras, but in Tensorflow I've needed to set 3 or 4 seeds. P.s.: do not forget about seeds if you are using dropout layers.

Comment: Did you splitted your dataset as train/validation/test or did a kfold cross validation ? Try to graph those first, you may be underfitting / overfitting